# How would you exit a loop with a string literal in Python?

Tags: python, loops, break, nameerror

For some reason, I get a `NameError` exception raised when I try to execute this code:

```
while True:
    fileString = input("Enter your command: ")
    print(fileString)
    if fileString is "end":
        break
    else:
        print("\nSomething went wrong! Please try again.")
        continue
print("The program will now shut down.")
```

I would like to break the loop when "end" is entered in the input.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: **tl;dr** Never use the `is` keyword, as a beginner. It's not the droid you want. Use `==`

Comment: Everyone's in such a hurry to answer, 3 different people seem to have missed the NameError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Two things to note here.  
(1) Use raw_input(), and not input(). With integers, input() will be ok  
    But you seem to be entering string.  
    fileString = raw_input("Enter your command: ")
(2) Change the if statement to  
    if fileString == "end":
```

Comment: `input` is only wrong if this is Python 2. In Python 3, `input` is the same as Py2's `raw_input`; no implicit `eval`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It's the only place in the posted code where a NameError could have originated, so it's probably Python 2 `input`. If it's not, we need to see more of the OP's code.

Comment: I am using Python 3.(the newest version), compiling in IDLE. This solution worked. Thank you balabhi :)

Comment: @moshulu: If this worked, you're not using Python 3. Check carefully; maybe you're mixing Python 2 IDLE with a Python 3 `python` command or something.

Answer (score 3):

```
if fileString is "end"
```

That line is your problem, compare fileString's equality to "end" with `==` (tests for value equality) and not `is` (tests for pointer equality).

On a side note, I suggest removing the redundant `continue` on line 8.

Comment: this is not the problem you are looking for. read the question again

Answer (score 0):

In Python, 'is' tests for identity. To test for equality, replace the 'is' with '=='. It may work then.